# How to enter Excerpt in biblatex?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

Are any of the entry types in biblatex particularly well suited for referencing an excerpt? For example:

```
Lucas, Édouard. Recherches sur plusieurs ouvrages de Léonard de Pise et sur diverses
questions d’arithmétique supérieure. (Extrait du Bullettino di bibliografia e di storia
delle scienze matematiche e fisiche. Tomo X. — Marzo, Aprile e Maggio 1877). — Rome : 
Imprimerie des sciences mathématiques et physiques, 1877. — 122 p. (in Fr.)
```

Where the above is an excerpt from **Bullettino di bibliografia e di storia delle scienze matematiche e fisiche.**, but is now published separately.

[Here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Recherches_Sur_Plusieurs_Ouvrages_De_L%C3%A9onard_De_Pise_Et_Sur_Diverses_Questions_D%E2%80%99Arithm%C3%A9tique_Sup%C3%A9rieure,_%C3%89douard_Lucas_%281877%29.pdf) is the link to the cover of this document.

I thought of using *inbook*, but I am not sure if that fits exactly.

Comment: Could this not be handled using a book entry with the excerpt information in a subtitle/titleaddon/note field?

Comment: I agree with Audrey. At 122 pages published in a standalone form, your specific text looks to me more like a book or a booklet. If Biblatex had support for an `origjournal` field, I'd recommend coding, but your best option for now is adding info to a note.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use a different entry for this kind of situation, something like `orig-REFNAME`. The result is to bibliographic entries in your Bibliography, what I'm afraid is not what you need since what really matters here is the standards you have to follow..., like @Martigan said.

Here's an example of how i would do the references:

```
@book{REFNAME,
  author = {Lucas, Édouard},
  title = {Recherches sur plusieurs ouvrages de Léonard de Pise et sur diverses questions d’arithmétique supérieure},
  address = {Rome},
  publisher = {Imprimerie des sciences mathématiques et physiques},
  year = {1877},
  totalpages = {122},
  language = {french},
}
@article{orig-REFNAME,
  crossref = {REFNAME}
  journal = {Bullettino di bibliografia e di storia delle scienze matematiche e fisiche},
  volume = {Tomo X},
  date = {1877-03/1877-05},
}
```

But if you need that the main entry refers the original publication, I would add an `addendum = {Extrait du \textcite{orig-REFNAME}}`, which impossibilitates the use of the `crossref`. In this case, I would do something like this:

```
@book{REFNAME,
  author = {Lucas, Édouard},
  title = {Recherches sur plusieurs ouvrages de Léonard de Pise et sur diverses questions d’arithmétique supérieure},
  address = {Rome},
  publisher = {Imprimerie des sciences mathématiques et physiques},
  year = {1877},
  totalpages = {122},
  language = {french},
  addendum = {Extrait du \textcite{orig-REFNAME}},
}
@article{orig-REFNAME,
  author = {Lucas, Édouard},
  title = {Recherches sur plusieurs ouvrages de Léonard de Pise et sur diverses questions d’arithmétique supérieure},
  journal = {Bullettino di bibliografia e di storia delle scienze matematiche e fisiche},
  volume = {Tomo X},
  date = {1877-03/1877-05},
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The question is, I think, more suited to your supervisor if you have one. Perhaps there are some clear instructions in your field as well as to how to treat this case. 
However, in the absence of such input, I would recommend to use the inbook or perhaps even better incollection, since the excerp is printed at the same time as the Bulletino.